# Executing Ghostscript on a 64 bit command shell from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, cmd, ghostscript

My Excel VBA macro creates a the `gs.cmd` file containing the following lines:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin64c.exe" @gsparams
echo %ProgramFiles%
pause
```

Then executes `Shell "gs.cmd"`.

The resulting PDF file generated by Ghostscript misses a few links and the console shows `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

If I start a `cmd.exe` from the Start menu and execute the same `gs.cmd` script, the resulting PDF file is correct and the console shows `C:\Program Files`.

The PDF file it contains many 36"x24" CAD drawings, with mostly vector content and a few large bitmaps, with hundreds of bookmarks and thousands of links defined in the pdfmarks file.

The only difference I see between the executions is that one seems to be 32 bit and the other 64 bit.

I don't understand why Ghostscript makes a perfect job in the 64 bit instance, but in the 32 bit instance does most of the job correctly and it just misses the creation of about 5% of the links. I would expect for it to either fail or work.

I googled around to see if I could get the `Shell` to run in a 64 bit environment, but I didn't find a solution.

How can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: @yms: I don't understand the problem either. I'm just trying to list the differences between the test and the run environment. I tried with both `Shell "gs.cmd"` and `Shell "cmd /c gs.cmd"`, and it's the same. Perhaps Ghostscript uses some environment variables?

Comment: Interesting... Indeed that may be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a second .cmd file that launches the cmd version that you want?

It may look like this:

launcher.cmd :

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\cmd.exe /c c:\temp\gs.cmd
```

The 32 bit version of cmd.exe will be inside `%SYSTEMROOT%\Syswow64\` on 64 bit systems. On a 32 bit system I guess the script will use the only cmd.exe available (`%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\cmd.exe`) so no problem there.